# Hightchart Angularjs feeding controller

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to plot a graph with Hightchart, my data comes from an REST web service.

I am using angularjs (1.5) to get the data.

my Service look like :

```
app.factory('ServicesImpl', function($http){ 

    var obj = {};

    obj.getData = function(){ 
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/chartDepense/');
    };

    return obj;
});
```

my controller is :

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope, ServicesImpl) { 

    $scope.chart =  ServicesImpl.getData().then(function(r){
        return  r.data;
    });

    console.log($scope.chart);  

    $scope.chartOptions = {
            title: {
                text: $scope.chart.libelle
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: $scope.chart.categories ,
                title: {
                    text: 'les X'
                }
            },      
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'les Y'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: $scope.chart.peroides
            }]
    };   

});
```

and I got this :

[image]

I don't know can I can get my data in my controller to put in chartConfig?

Comment: code sources :
https://gitlab.com/java2000/hightchart

Comment: It seems that `categorie` and `data` variables are strings. You need to convert `categorie` to an array of strings and `data` to array of numbers.